# How to create a Query with lucene PointRangeQueryBuilder

Tags: lucene

I want to programatically create a RangeQuery on a lucene field.
I found PointRangeQueryBuilder but I did not find any example how to use it in a Java code block. 
Can anybody give me a hint (code example) or a pointer to one example ?

Answer (score 0):

That class is used by the xml queryParser.  For an example of how to use that queryParser, lucene comes with at demo of it `org.apache.lucene.demo.xmlparser`.

To simply create a range query against two pointValues, you can do it like:

```java
Query query = IntPoint.newRangeQuery("myField", 2, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot.